# i am trying to get base64 string of an image

Tags: python, html, django

trying to get base64 string of an image, which is uploaded locally by the user.
my html code is-

```
<div class="col-md-4">
      <label class="control-label"></label>
      <input type="file" name="galleryImage" class="filestyle" data-buttonText="Select a Image">
      <input class="btn btn-sm btn-info btn-block" name="getImageUrl" type="submit" Style="width: 100px;">
</div>
```

and in my views

```
galleryImageURL = request.POST.get('galleryImage')
print(galleryImageURL)
galleryImage = requests.get(galleryImageURL).content
print(galleryImage)
base64EncodedImageString = imageBase64Encode(galleryImage)
print(base64EncodedImageString)

def imageBase64Encode(galleryImage):
    with open(galleryImage, "rb") as image_file:
        encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
    return encoded_string
```

i am getting error

```
Invalid URL '763814bc03a9838a7bae23ad4867ec01.jpg': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://763814bc03a9838a7bae23ad4867ec01.jpg?
```

Comment: You need to get the temporary directory where that image is stored, and create a full path based on that. I can't remember how to do it off the top of my head, sorry, but that's the problem. I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here galleryImage is a file instance and not a url. 
So you are reading it wrong.

Try this in your view.

```
galleryImage = request.FILES['galleryImage'].read()
base64string = base64.encodestring(galleryImage)
```

Also don't forget to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form.

Comment: it throws an error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'`

Comment: Updated the first line. can you try now.

Answer (score 1):

No schema means that you need to supply the `http://` (or `https://`) to the path.

Edit your path to start with `http://` and it should work.